# How to export data tree using SFDX with User object lookup field

Tags: salesforcedx, error, data-export

I've a custom object with a custom `User` lookup field. When I use `force:data:tree:export` command results into following errors:

> Reference User not found for UserLookupField__c.  Skipping record
>   a1X0K000003bIyEUAU.

Does anyone know how to export data with a User Lookup field in it?